# Windows 8.1 won't shut down or hibernate after dual booting Ubuntu. Hybrid boot issues?

Tags: windows-8.1, grub, shutdown, hybrid-boot

So I installed Ubuntu 15.4 on a different partition just like I used to do with Windows 7. I'm using GRUB 2 to choose the OS and I can boot into the two operating systems just fine.

When I try to shut down or hibernate from Windows, however, the computer doesn't shut down or hibernate. If I want to shut down the computer I have to restart and then hit the power button at the boot sequence. This is, of course, not optimal.
I think that this might be a hybrid boot issue but I am not sure.

Comment: If you suspect hybrid boot did you try turning it off?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The computer shuts down when I disable hybrid boot but it still doesn't hibernate.

Comment: What sort of system is this? Did you try [disabling and re-enabling hibernation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/920730)? If that doesn't help then edit your question and post the output of `powercfg /a`.